# How do you handle multiple Quarry as a Ranger?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, ranger

A ranger having the Battlefield Archer PP can use this power:

> Battlefield Experience (11th level): You can designate more than one creature as your quarry at a time, up to a number equal to your Wisdom modifier. In addition, any attack made against a quarry receives a +1 bonus to attack rolls.

Quarry:

> A ranger with the Hunter's Quarry class feature can, once per turn as a minor action, **designate the nearest visible enemy** as his or her quarry. This designation lasts until the encounter ends, the quarry is defeated, or the ranger designates a different target. **Once per round**, the ranger deals 1d6 per tier damage when hitting his or her quarry with an attack.

Let's say we have 3 enemies at different locations. Would you need to move through the battlefield until your first target is the nearest and then continue doing so until every enemy is marked? Once they are marked by your Quarry, do you no longer need them to be the nearest to benefit, **once per round**, of your bonus to damage?

*English isn't my first language, so I can try to reformulate if necessary.*

Answer (score 6):

What you wrote is correct.

You need each target to be your nearest foe at the moment you apply the quarry, so you either need to move around or to wait for enemies to move (or for allies to move them) in order to have more than one quarry.

After that, they are all quarries until they die, which means that you could decide to hit an enemy that wasn't the one you were focus-firing and deal the quarry damage without spending a minor to swap quarries and then another minor next turn to go back to the first enemy.

Comment: So, even if the fight continue and the targets are moving, you can stand still and hit all of your quarry even if they are not the nearest ?

Comment: With that paragon path, once an enemy is your quarry, they stay your quarry even if you designate another one (that's explicitly laid out in the 4e Customer Service FAQ).  Also, the entry you have was subject to some errata.  See https://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2295/